# managing transaction using content provider calls

Tags: android

I have a ContentProvider that exposes CRUD calls for my database. Singleton patter is used to maintain single instance of DatabaseHelper and there by SQliteDatabase. Multiple applications will use my content provider.

Is there a way to expose `beginTransaction`, `setTransactionSuccessful` and `endTransaction` using my ContentProvider.

applyBatch can be implemented with transaction. But then it will be fixed to execute all batch operation in transaction and there wont be choice to the users of my content provider.

Using Call API for exposing these 3 operation doesn't work even though the instance of SQLiteDatabase used in all the content provider API is the same. Any other way to achieve this?

Comment: There isn't a way to expose those through the ContentProvider but you could pass some additional info to your used uris to let it know that it should work with the underlying database with transactions.

Comment: i don't get it. are you using multiple ContentProvider implementations for one database? why you are using singleton pattern? there is no need for this in one CP. Are you closing the DataBase instance after every operation? ContentProvider.call should work (but you should not doing this as db abstraction should not go outside the CP)

Comment: Just single database exposed with one content provider. Nothing wrong in using sigleton for databasehelper and it is recomended pattern for handling many scenarios. Just one database connection is open and is never closed. (will get closed when process dies/killed).

Comment: actually all these APIs can be exposed with call method with different method names. But the issues is that one call API to start transaction , never able to end the transaction with another call API even though both calls will use the same SQLiteDatabase object as it is same instance.

Comment: `never able to end the transaction with another call API` error or just transaction is not commited? are you are using different threads?

Comment: just not committed.. no errors